# Creating new data dir in mysql gives a lot of errors

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql server on my fedora machine. Now I want to run another instance of mysql server on the same machine on a different port.

For this I needed to create a different data directory. 
Mysql server is installed on the default location /usr/local/mysql and the default data dir location is /usr/local/mysql/data

Now for creating new data dir when I fire this command

```
./scripts/mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql2
```

It gives me whole lot of errors with innodb saying something like

```
InnoDB: Error number 17 means 'File exists'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2014-04-29 10:31:51 32072 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot create file './mysql/innodb_table_stats.ibd'

2014-04-29 10:31:51 32072 [ERROR] InnoDB: The file './mysql/innodb_table_stats.ibd' already exists though the corresponding table did not exist in the InnoDB data dictionary. Have you moved InnoDB .ibd files around without using the SQL commands DISCARD TABLESPACE and IMPORT TABLESPACE, or did mysqld crash in the middle of CREATE TABLE? You can resolve the problem by removing the file './mysql/innodb_table_stats.ibd' under the 'datadir' of MySQL.
ERROR: 1813  Tablespace for table '`mysql`.`innodb_table_stats`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.
2014-04-29 10:31:51 32072 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are you using [mysql_multi](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld-multi.html)? if not, you'll want to read up on setting all that up as it sounds like that's what you want

Comment: No I am not using mysql_multi. My goal is to create 2 seperate process es for mysql on 2 separate ports and configure them with 2 separate ram size. One process should not take 20 % of system memory and the other should not take 70 % of the system memory. Is it possible in mysql_multi?

Comment: Also i would like to have 2 separate databases for these 2 processes

Comment: Yep. You'll definitely want to read up on mysql_multi. It's all setup in the _my.cnf_. You can configure it however you want, it sets up as many independent processes of mysql as you configure as well as data directories. There's far too much to post on here however it sounds like its the exact path you'll want to head down.

Comment: Thanks mittens for the inputs. I had a look at mysqld_multi. I can give the path to data dir but I need to create that data dir and for that I have to use the command as specified above which is failing. Is there a way wherein mysqld_multi creates a data dir for me.

Comment: You have to create the data directories via that command. Did you move your data directory from the its initial location after installation? Also, when running `mysql_install_db` you want to make sure you specify the user if not running it as the `mysql` user (or whoever will be running the `mysqld` process)

Comment: I have both the .frm and .ibd files but it still gives a lot errors like the below
2014-04-29 11:29:51 7f8b325b0740  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2014-04-29 11:29:51 3247 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'VegayanMarch26/ROUTERTRAFFIC_LINK_SCALE1_TBL'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html

Comment: Id double check that the directory itself exists and has the correct permissions. IIRC mysql_install_db won't _make_ the directories but it will populate them as long as they exist with the correct permissions